# Combining attributes of tiff layer file and shapefiles they fall into?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I am currently using ArcMap 10.5 and having trouble combining information of two layers. One is a tiff file with land classification data, and the other is a shapefile with broad scale regions.

Is there a way to combine the two layers so that the attribute table for the tiff file lists which of the shapefile regions it falls into or the percentage of cover for that specific shapefile?

Comment: Convert your raster to a polygon dataset then do a union of the two datasets.

Comment: Are you looking for a raster output or a tabular summary?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to have a look at [Zonal Statistics as Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics-as-table.htm) tool. As Hornbydd commented, you cannot explicitly overlay raster and vector data. They should be converted to one or another, either manually or on-the-fly as done by Zonal Statistics as Table.

Make sure you have a shape-area field calculated for your regions. Run the tool by setting zones as your regions shapefile and land cover as the value raster, get the table and join this table to your regions shapefile. And then use AREA field of the table and shape-area from your shapefile to find the proportions in a new field, say COVER_PERC. Finally use [Pivot Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/pivot-table.htm) on the joined table by setting your region IDs as Input Field, raster values (corresponding to the land cover) as Pivot Table and newly calculated field (COVER_PERC) as Value Field.